# Generating Swift models from Core Data entities

Tags: xcode, core-data, model, swift, nsmanagedobject

**Update for Xcode 8:**

In Xcode 8, one needs to go to the Core Data Model Editor and Show the File Inspector. Near the bottom is an option for code generation. Select Swift.

**Edit**: I found the solution to generate a Swift model from Core Data entity:

On Xcode:

*Editor > Create NSManagedOjbect > Click button "Next" > Click button "Next" > Select "Swift" Langage > Click button "Create"*

---

I tried Swift langage by creating a new Swift project on Xcode 6 beta using Core Data.

When I generate my models from my Core Data's entities, Xcode creates Objective-C models.

Is there a way to generate Swift model rather than Obejctive-C model with Core Data ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Lets have a look on the Objective-C way:

**Person.h** (Header-File)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Person : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

**Person.m** (Implementation-File)

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person
@dynamic name;
@end
```

## Swift

The documentation already included in Xcode6-Beta says:

> Core Data provides the underlying storage and implementation of properties in subclasses of the NSManagedObject class. Add the @NSManaged attribute before each property definition in your managed object subclass that corresponds to an attribute or relationship in your Core Data model. Like the @dynamic attribute in Objective-C, the @NSManaged attribute informs the Swift compiler that the storage and implementation of a property will be provided at runtime. However, unlike @dynamic, the @NSManaged attribute is available only for Core Data support.

So that is how I would rewrite the above example for Swift (not tested):

**Person.swift**

```
import CoreData

class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name : NSString

}
```

And according to your question I think the subclass-generation-feature might be not included in Xcode6 yet. Did you made sure that you have chosen "Swift" as programming language when you were creating the Cocoa-Project in Xcode?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes I checked, I chose the Swift langage when I created my project.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the subclass generation feature is not included for swift in this version of Xcode.

Comment: `import Cocoa` generated the error "No such module 'cocoa'" for me. I switched it to `import CoreData` and it was happy with that.

Comment: You can't import Cocoa from iOS. You are developing for iOS, right?

Comment: Note: To use this example you must put @objc(Person) before class. Otherwise any attempt to access a Person instance will result in a crash. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: FYI, Xcode 6 beta 3 allows auto-creation of managed-object subclasses (although annoyingly the default is Objective-C, even in a Swift project)

Comment: Xcode Version 6.1.1  full supported, select your .xcdatamodeld Editor->create NSManagedObject Subclass ...

Answer (score 12):

You can get Swift model back using `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName` but you must edit your core data model file and not use `Person` as a Class Entity but `<ProjectName>.Person` else it returns `NSManagedObject`...

Using `println()` you won't see `Person` instance but something like `<_TtC5ProjectName4Person: 0xc9ad5f0>` but calling methods on this will prove it's a `Person` instance for real. I guess it's just the way for Swift to generate unique class names, not conflict and CoreData methods show this internal mechanism.

The [Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html):

> Swift classes are namespaced—they’re scoped to the module (typically, the project) they are compiled in. To use a Swift subclass of the NSManagedObject class with your Core Data model, prefix the class name in the Class field in the model entity inspector with the name of your module.

Comment: Arg that had me stumped... Is this documented anywhere?  I feel as though this is likely to change before release

Comment: I use this method - decorating the class name with the project name - and that works from for running the app, but my Tests that use core data throw an invalid cast method.  Any work around for that?

Comment: @DanielD did you find the solution for the casting problem in your test target? Cause that's what I'm struggling with right now...

Comment: @Fabien Penso Can you create example project on Github?

Answer (score 11):

According to Apple's video regarding What's new In CoreData frame: 38mins (WWDC2014 Session 225), in inspector's Data Model, prefix the class name with the project name. Like **projectName.Doctor**

I've tried this but what will happen is that the generated managed object class becomes: **projectName.swift** instead of **Doctor.swift**. Even the class declaration becomes **class projectName: ManagedObject**

**Solution:**

In Data model inspector, just specify the Name & Class of your object to what name you want, **example: Doctor**

After you generated an object model and selecting Swift, this will create a file (**Doctor.swift**).

Now, when inserting new records in Core Data, you might an experience error *"Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead"* even if you cast the newly inserted object to a correct object name.

To solve this, you just need to add **@objc(class name)** above the class declaration. See sample below.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Doctor)
class Doctor: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

Then:

```
let doctorManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Doctor", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Doctor
doctorManagedObject.name = "John" // you can now use dot syntax instead of setValue
```

Save context to commit insert.

Comment: Save context to commit insert would be context.save(nil)

Comment: what does @objc(Doctor) actually do ?

Comment: @objc(Doctor) means that you are exposing the declaration of Doctor class to Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

I tested @NSManaged, it didn't work. :( .
But mixed models files(.h) generated by xcdatamodel, it succeed. 
please read the doc and code in https://github.com/iascchen/SwiftCoreDataSimpleDemo

Comment: Try adding `@objc(ClassName)` above the Swift class

Comment: This code is updated for xcode6 gm. We still have to add @objc now. https://github.com/iascchen/SwiftCoreDataSimpleDemo

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can just add `#import "Person.h"` to the bridging header, `Project-Bridging-Header.h` that Xcode generates for you (if you accepted it's offer to generate). Then you can use all the auto-generated Obj-C as if it were native Swift.

Answer (score 3):

*Editor* -> *Create NSManagedObject Subclass* works fine for Swift

Simply go through all the usual steps, but when you get to creating the files, choose Language 'Swift' if it's the first time you've used *Create NSManagedObject Subclass* with a Swift project it'll be defaulting to Objective C

Answer (score 2):

**For XCode 12.**

You can change generating model language.
[image]