# Parse "unrecognized selector sent to instance" while accessing PFObject members

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I've got a weird issue with accessing member fields using dot notation. Example:

SettingsModel

```
class SettingsModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Settings"
    }

    @NSManaged var name:String
    @NSManaged var code:String
    @NSManaged var friend:FriendsModel

}
```

FriendsModel

```
class FriendsModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Friends"
    }

    @NSManaged var user:PFUser
    @NSManaged var settings:SettingsModel
}
```

When I try to access friends name using `mySettings.friend.settings.name` I'm getting unrecognized selector on "settings".

But interestingly enough when I use `(mySettings.friend["settings"] as SettingsModel).name` it works. I've intentionally omitted all the conditional unwrapping, etc. - I've got valid PFObject of the right type with all the data...

I'm sure it's something trivial but can't figure it out... Any help would be appreciated. Using Parse 1.8.2.

Comment: Would you give us more context? Like the whole class declarations?

Comment: You mean the model classes? They are just standard Parse subclass templates but I've added them anyway. Cheers

Comment: @Tom Did you figure out what the issue was? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's still not working for me. I'm using the workaround mentioned in original question

Comment: Why using `@NSManaged` which is for CoreData? So the work around for the getter/setter and the issue with the dot notation seems correct (see the quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015789/1801544)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `FriendsModel` was not successfully registered as a Parse subclass, despite your implementation of `PFSubclassing`. It could be the case that the `initialize()` of `FriendsModel` is not yet called when you access it via `mySettings.friend.settings.name`.

To solve this issue you can register your `FriendsModel` subclass earlier with Parse by calling `FriendsModel.registerSubclass()`, just before the location where you call `Parse.setApplicationId(..)`.

This is how I solved these kinds of issues myself, I hope it helps in your case too.

Comment: I suspected that might be the problem originally so I've added SettingsModel.initialize() and FriendsModel.initialize() as the very first thing in AppDelegate. But alas didn't help.

Comment: registerSubclass() method worked for me and solved the problem :)

Comment: I am having the same issue, definitely calling [MyClass registerSubclass], and even tried re-arranging it to make sure that the class that gets nested is registered first in case that causes a problem.

Although, the key accessor worked for me to get around the issue for now.

Answer (score 3):

wow...I think I found the reason behind your problem, but it would be one of those "how in hell can this be the reason" type of solutions. I came across this thread because I received the same error message and I'm pretty much in a similar environment (parse, subclassing, swift). The line where my app crashed was this one:

`let setOpts = self.thing?.settingOptions`

where the variable "thing" represents a PFObject as well as "settingOptions". So I thought that maybe it was also a problem of falsely registered subclasses, although I think that's not necessary anymore in the recent Parse versions (I'm using v1.15.1). Anyway, the workaround you provided helped at first, but made my app crash at that next line:

```
if (self.thing?.setting != nil) {...}
```

and then it got me thinking...wait a minute...there were several other properties of "thing" accessed through dot notation in between which did not crash, so why again here?! When I checked back at your post it hit me right in the face. I hope everybody sees it by now because you might not believe me if I tell you...but I'm gonna anyways:

> The properties we use all start with **setting**.

And that seems to be it. I don't know if they shouldn't start with "set" or "setti", but definitely not with "setting". As soon as I changed the name to something completely different it worked. Maybe the classname is relevant, too, but mine starts with a prefix so "setting" is only part of the name. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: wow. I can't believe how lucky I am that I found this answer. I could easily of seen myself troubleshooting this for the next 5 hours. Thanks man.

Comment: omfg. I can confirm this. I had a PFObject subclass with a property called "sets". (i.e. sets of repetitions, for an exercise). Inexplicable crash. Googled in desperation, and stumbled across this answer. Changed to "repSets", and works. :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer as to why it's happening but i'm using a workaround that is slightly cleaner in my mind as the workaround is only in one place. Namely using the setter and getter functionality of swift.

```
class SettingsModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Settings"
}

@NSManaged var name:String
@NSManaged var code:String
var friend:FriendsModel
    {
        get
        {
             return self["friend"] as! FriendsModel 
        }
        set
        {
             self["friend"] = newValue
        }
    }

}
```