# swift core data relationship one to many for own entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsset

Hi I'm building a newspaper database which have item relationship to itself (item can have many other item as child)

here is my `NSmanageObjectSubclass`

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
extension Item {

    @NSManaged var by: String?
    @NSManaged var dead: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var descendants: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var score: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var text: String?
    @NSManaged var time: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var type: String?
    @NSManaged var url: String?
    @NSManaged var kids: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var parent: Item?
    @NSManaged var parts: NSSet?

}
```

Problem is that how can i add `item` to property `kids: NSSet`
the relationship define is one to many to its own with reverse. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

my coredata xcmodel
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add relationships in the XCDataModel?

Comment: Yes i set one to many relationship with inverse for item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** update your class Managed Object class to use Sets instead of NSSet

```
     import Foundation
        import CoreData
        extension Item {

            @NSManaged var by: String?
            @NSManaged var dead: NSNumber?
            @NSManaged var descendants: NSNumber?
            @NSManaged var id: NSNumber?
            @NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber?
            @NSManaged var score: NSNumber?
            @NSManaged var text: String?
            @NSManaged var time: NSDate?
            @NSManaged var title: String?
            @NSManaged var type: String?
            @NSManaged var url: String?
            @NSManaged var kids: Set<Item>
            @NSManaged var parent: Item?
            @NSManaged var parts: NSSet?

        }
```

**Secondly** create a fetchRequest named getItemByID with expression 
id == $ID

**Third** create a function to get item by id

```
    func getItemById(ID:String) -> Item?
    {
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest = self.managedObjectModel.fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName("getItemByID", substitutionVariables: ["ID": ID])!
        do {
            let fetchedResult = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Item]
            if fetchedResult.count > 0 {
                let result = fetchedResult[0]
                return result
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not fetch \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

After that you have many options to set relations

a) you create relation after adding parent & child to coreData

```
func addChildToParent(childID:String,parentID:String)
    {
        if let childItem = getItemById(childID)
        {
           if let parentItem = getItemById(parentID)
           {
              parentItem.kids.insert(menuItemCatering)
              childItem.parent = parentItem
           }
        }
       saveContext()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I can add relationship now. The tricky part is to use Set<Item> instead of the default NSSet. Is this a bug? In objectiveC I can use Xcode to generate NSManageSubclass working find but in Swift the relation to own entity seem not working automatically

Comment: It is not a bug, but it is easier than using NSSet & getting mutable copy of it then save it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to automatically create relationships and properties.

[Generating Swift models from Core Data entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015185/generating-swift-models-from-core-data-entities)

i.e. 
Edit: I found the solution to generate a Swift model from Core Data entity:

On `Xcode`:

> Editor > Create NSManagedOjbect > Click button "Next" > Click button
>   "Next" > Select "Swift" Langage > Click button "Create"

Here is the link on how to create a relationship from scratch. This is a very well explained and awesome tutorial. Go through this and you'll be able to understand all the things. 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505

Comment: Hi i already created using that. But how to add item to the set for examle item.kids.add(kid) or something similar

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I know how to create relationship. But my problem is to add item to relationship to own entity. I have uploaded picture of my coredata and generated NSmanage Object to question. but cannot add item to kids (NSSet property)